# Use callback to check and return an object from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to get { city: "Malden", population: 2200 } if I console.log(smallPop(array, callback)
Using reduce, filter or find, not sort method.

```
const array = [
  { city: "Malden", population: 2200 },
  { city: "Chelsea", population: 3000 },
  { city: "Cambridge", population: 5400 }
];

function callback(array) {
return array.map(element => element.population)
}

function smallPop(array, callback) {
}
```

Comment: Your `cb()` function accepts no parameters

Comment: `if(cb(element.population === [min]))` What's this for?

Comment: I would expect a function called `minBy` to accept also a desired property like... `"population"` i.e: `minBy(arr, prop)` The `cb` is useless, since I'd also expect such function to `return` the needed

Comment: If you are not concerned of sorting in order to find min, you can always sort the array of objects using a "sorter" function. Then take the first item.

Comment: This code makes very little sense. The callback function should just operate on a single element, not call `map()`. The reduce function shouldn't be inside the loop, since it doesn't depend on the current element of the array. You should use the callback function to get the property to compare, not hard-code `curr.population`.

Comment: Similar to @Phil and @DreamBold, I think you might have some errors in your code and/or I'm just unsure what your goal is in this. You may want to add some more information to make it more clear.
Based on my understanding, though, you may want to try using `array.map()` or `array.forEach()`, instead of the `for(let element of array)`. I'm pretty sure it would allow you to do the same thing, but I think it would make it more clear as to what your goal is.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect a function called `minBy` to accept also a desired property like... `"population"` i.e: `minBy(arr, prop)` The `cb` is useless, since I'd also expect such function to `return` the needed

```js
const minBy = (arr, prop) =>
  arr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev[prop] < curr[prop] ? prev : curr);

const array = [
  { city: "Chelsea", population: 3000, area: 300 },
  { city: "Malden", population: 2200, area: 400 },
  { city: "Cambridge", population: 5400, area: 200 }
];

console.log("Min by population:", minBy(array, "population"));
console.log("Min city by area:", minBy(array, "area").city);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:

```
array.map(element => element.population)
```

With:

```
array.sort((a,b) => a.population - b.population)[0]
```

That should do it, as in the demo below:

```js
const array = [
  { city: "Malden", population: 2200 },
  { city: "Chelsea", population: 3000 },
  { city: "Cambridge", population: 5400 }
];

function callback(array) {
  //sort from smallest population to largest
  //object with smallest population would be at index 0 ... [0]
  return array.sort((a,b) => a.population - b.population)[0];
}

function smallPop(array, callback) {
    return callback( array );
}

console.log( smallPop(array, callback) );
```